# Safest spots when an asteroid hits?

Tags: geophysics, meteorite, natural-disasters, mass-extinction

I am breaking this question and no longer making an effort in refining it with the exception of adding an associated link with the scenarios.

I always wondered if a devastating asteroid was predicted to impact the Earth where in the world would I have the highest chances of surviving the blast and short-term aftermath like seismic activity.

Which of these scenarios would have the best chances of survival?

**Scenario 1.** In the air of some type blimp or aircraft on the opposite side of the Earth?
[How is radiation dispersed by Earth's atmosphere?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13528/how-is-radiation-dispersed-by-earths-atmosphere)

**Scenario 2.** On or Underground in a cave?
[Can a shock wave be felt all the way around the Earth?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13530/can-a-shock-wave-be-felt-all-the-way-around-the-earth)

**Scenario 3.** In a submarine or capsule underwater?
[Does being under water provide any protection from a asteriod?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13531/does-being-under-water-provide-any-protection-from-a-asteriod)

No point on Earth is truly safe without the known impact of the asteroid, but are there points on the Earth, even if you are on the other side, that you don't want to be like near fault lines?

Comment: Regarding your scenario 2: the mantle is solid rock. Things don't "sink" in it, at least not in human time scales.

Comment: I don't know if it's precisely Earth science but some safety tips for asteroid impacts wouldn't be a bad idea.   A big one that heats up the Earth you might want a cellar (not everyone has access to a cellar, but it would help keep cool).   #1 tip is don't watch it from a glass window, when the pressure wave hits the glass will shatter.  You're mostly OK watching until it hits the ground but then get away from anything glass, don't stand by the window watching after the impact unless you want a face full of glass.

Comment: this question needs the `meteorology` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being in a submarine in the ocean is not a good idea because if a large asteroid hits the ocean the shock wave created, and its energy, would be very large. If the submarine survives intact its occupants may not. The occupants could be thrown about so much they liquidize & turn into people puree.

Similarly being airborne in a blimp or airplane would be problematic for the reasons you state.

Being on the opposite side of the world to the impact site, whether underground in a cave or on the Earth's surface, might be OK if you are far away from the coast so the tsunami wave from a asteroid hitting the ocean doesn't inundate you.

As for, as you state,

> the crust of the Earth may change drastically with the whole cave sinking in the ocean or worse into the mantle

that won't happen. The [Earth's crust](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/data/crust/) is about 30 km thick. It can withstand some beating from an asteroid and it won't be sinking into the Mantle just because of an asteroid strike. A cave sinking into the ocean or being swamped by a tsunami might happen if the cave is near the coast and/or the asteroid strike is close by.