# Does being in the air provide any protection from an asteroid?

Tags: meteorology, wind, meteorite, atmospheric-radiation, natural-disasters

How does radiation and shock waves from a radioactive asteroid or atomic explosion disperse throughout Earth's atmosphere?

Are there specific areas on Earth that are less likely to receive the shock wave or radiation by being on the other side of the Earth and/or land or wind characteristics like being in a deep valley?

I'm trying to go with the worst case survivable scenario if the asteroid hit with the possibility of hitting a nuclear reactor, arsenal or deposit of uranium.

[image: Image of mushroom cloud heights]

#### Related:

> *This is from [a broad question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/safest-spots-when-an-asteroid-hits) that I am breaking up in 3 questions. Feel free to edit.*

Which of these scenarios would have a smaller chance of being struck?

- In the air of some type blimp or aircraft on the opposite side of the Earth?

[Does being under water provide any protection from a asteroid?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13531/does-being-under-water-provide-any-protection-from-a-asteroid)

Comment: The link to the asteroid question has an answer posted, so there's a solution to that one.

Comment: @Imtherealsanic That question was to broad and doesn't give any real locations?

Comment: So you're asking it again _(heads up: it might be marked `[duplicate]`)_?

Comment: @Imtherealsanic can it be a duplicate of a closed answer the was to broad? What else should I do to it to make that not happen?

Comment: I'm rethinking what I said about it being marked `[duplicate]`. I'm pretty sure it won't be marked `[duplicate]` if there's more than one question being asked.

Comment: What. Are you asking how is the fallout from a meteor strike dispersed, or the fallout from a nuclear explosion? We don't know whether nature can cause nuclear explosion. I find your first phrase massively confusing.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I reworded it. does that make it any less confusing?

Comment: I think it's clearer now. But why do you think there would be a 'natural atomic explosion from an asteroid impact'? Asteroid or meteor impacts release simply gravitational energy, not nuclear ones.

Comment: Ah, that's a totally different question then. I would suggest another edit of your question to write exactly that. Maybe consider erasing the 'nuclear explosion' aspect, because that's just not going to happen.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape is this any better?

Comment: I think you have a fundamental flaw in your thinking.  "Radiation" isn't really a separate thing, it's just dust which happens to have radioactive atoms in it.  So the dispersal of radioactive fallout isn't really different from say ash (which really isn't ash :-)) from a volcano or smoke from a forest fire.

Comment: @jamesqf can you help me bring into scope? What about the question would you change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the radiation question, it is both absorbed and reflected into space. A lot of these processes are complex relations between atmosphere, magnetosphere, and solar radiation. Solar radiation does penetrate through as it drives everything we need or any creature needs to live, whether directly or indirectly. Aurora Borealis is caused by Solar radiation trapped in our atmosphere. This is why Ozone (O3) is so important as it does a massive support function of helping block those rays. Some of this radiation is reflected by the earth as thermal radiation. The magnetosphere also plays a role in capturing and diffusing such particles. A little more research may help, it is a very fascinating process. For more:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora

This was from courses in astronomy, hydrology, and my brain. Use wisely.